# Implementing polygon self-intersection in Python

Tags: python, geopandas, intersection, software-recommendations

Is there a Python library and function that would allow me to carry out polygon self-intersection on a single polygons layer, such as what is achieved by using the “SAGA Polygon self-intersection” tool in QGIS?

Every other python function I am finding for polygon intersections requires two separate layers to be intersected, rather than simply identifying the intersection between polygons in a single layer. This means that after running a polygons layer through this “polygon self-intersection” python function I am looking for, the geodataframe (if using geopandas) would then have additional rows added to it for additionally added spaces, the now identified intersection zones. There would as well involve the “ID” column including the IDs of all polygons that “make up” each intersection zone. For instance, polygon 1 and polygon 2 non overlapped spaces would have an “ID” of “1” and “2” respectively, and the overlapped region between these two polygons would have an “ID” of “1 | 2”, just like would be shown in QGIS after using the “SAGA Polygon self-intersection” tool. And as well, if we had a triple intersection with a polygon 3, the newly identified overlapped region between these three polygons would have an “ID” of “1 | 2 | 3”, just like would shown in QGIS after using the “SAGA Polygon self-intersection” tool.

I have not been able to find this within GeoPandas, as the GeoPandas polygon overlay functions appear to require two separate layers as inputs.

Here is what my shapefile looks like:
[image]

For reference:
The polygons I used were turned into their centroids and then buffered to 1/4 mile distance.

Here are the centroid coordinates of my buffers:

```
0     POINT (-13604211.017 4554804.595)
1     POINT (-13610727.382 4559245.985)
2     POINT (-13614171.974 4565380.476)
3     POINT (-13611036.059 4562595.117)
4     POINT (-13611986.274 4564049.187)
5     POINT (-13612916.586 4563936.448)
6     POINT (-13602234.338 4563015.607)
7     POINT (-13612399.115 4562654.820)
8     POINT (-13609971.081 4559031.424)
9     POINT (-13613293.685 4558725.535)
10    POINT (-13611922.699 4565876.467)
11    POINT (-13613733.483 4556423.327)
12    POINT (-13604485.660 4555089.412)
13    POINT (-13605022.256 4551148.583)
14    POINT (-13603752.634 4550764.525)
15    POINT (-13611500.291 4548909.827)
16    POINT (-13606620.852 4547777.264)
17    POINT (-13604949.018 4551387.605)
18    POINT (-13610794.814 4553121.618)
19    POINT (-13610077.870 4553680.083)
20    POINT (-13615078.994 4566347.140)
21    POINT (-13609346.498 4550470.678)
22    POINT (-13609117.309 4554812.264)
23    POINT (-13609179.017 4551117.796)
24    POINT (-13603320.178 4550288.519)
25    POINT (-13611568.431 4547933.755)
26    POINT (-13601285.925 4550978.405)
27    POINT (-13608327.200 4553650.316)
28    POINT (-13607025.788 4546911.740)
29    POINT (-13625355.222 4550774.185)
30    POINT (-13614118.477 4562602.638)
31    POINT (-13611030.521 4562315.516)
32    POINT (-13604582.190 4547459.957)
33    POINT (-13610192.502 4553936.027)
34    POINT (-13602412.265 4547187.654)
35    POINT (-13605394.544 4549989.133)
36    POINT (-13604610.731 4552881.663)
37    POINT (-13600146.915 4543612.151)
38    POINT (-13600058.162 4543634.806)
39    POINT (-13605164.136 4547391.426)
40    POINT (-13604729.135 4547419.234)
41    POINT (-13602534.183 4547255.310)
42    POINT (-13612207.081 4549163.977)
43    POINT (-13603950.618 4548378.891)
44    POINT (-13607061.377 4549046.392)
45    POINT (-13602507.710 4547248.595)
46    POINT (-13602514.041 4547218.106)
47    POINT (-13609998.343 4553042.678)
dtype: geometry
```

Comment: Can't you just give the overlay method the same layer as the second layer? Even if you can't, you could do a deep copy of the layer and give that as the second input.

Comment: Look at [Remove the intersecting parts in a set of polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429347/remove-the-intersecting-parts-in-a-set-of-polygons)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cross join the df to itself, then check for intersections and intersect.

This can be slow, or wont work with large dataframes.
For example 1000 rows will become 1 million with the cross join.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

df['id'] = np.arange(df.shape[0]) #Create an id column

#df.shape
#Out[48]: (48, 3)

cross = pd.merge(left=df, right=df, how='cross') #Cross join the dataframe to itself
#cross.shape
#Out[50]: (2304, 6)

cross = cross.loc[cross['id_x'] < cross['id_y']] #Remove self joins
#cross.shape
#Out[53]: (1128, 6)

cross = cross.loc[cross.geometry_x.intersects(cross.geometry_y)] #Select only polygons intersecting
#cross.shape
#Out[55]: (138, 6)

cross['inter'] = cross.geometry_x.intersection(cross.geometry_y) #Intersect them

cross = cross.set_geometry('inter') #The error was here. I thought set_geometry was inplace, but it is returning the dataframe
#cross.shape
#Out[60]: (138, 7)

cross = cross[[column for column in cross.columns if 'geom' not in column]] #Drop old geometries
cross.to_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/1milebuffers_overlaps.shp')
```

[image]
*Input purple, output black*

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough suggestion, this very much looks like what I am going for. And yes, to clarify, I mean polygons in the same layer intersecting, and not one polygon intersecting itself. Though in trying out your code suggestion, I am a bit confused about the output dataframe, since when I took a look at the final geodataframe "cross" at the end of your code, I was left with just 2 rows, but I am not sure why I ended up with only two rows, if when referring to my visual representation of my polygons I just added above, I have what I see is over a dozen intersection zones.

Comment: No, just polygons, where each row in the geodataframe corresponds to a unique, separate, individual polygon. In my case, each of these unique polygons are just distance buffers.

Comment: I just added the centroid coordinates to my post at the end.

Comment: The crs is "EPSG:3857". And here is the full properties of my polygons shapefile: `<Derived Projected CRS: EPSG:3857>
Name: WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- X[east]: Easting (metre)
- Y[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: World between 85.06°S and 85.06°N.
- bounds: (-180.0, -85.06, 180.0, 85.06)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator
- method: Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich`

Comment: This works for me now, thank you very much! Though in trying understand the logic here, in running this code suggestion on my buffers and then looking at each intersection polygon produced, I am trying to understand "x_id" and "y_id". To my understanding, "x_id" and "y_id" are the unique IDs of the polygons contributing to a given intersection region, and so "x_id" and "y_id" are the polygons "making up" a given intersection polygon in "1millbuffers_overlaps.shp". Though what if there is an overlap region made up by 3 polygons? Wouldn't there need to be a "z_id" column?

Comment: Nice! If there are 3 polygons overlapping their intersections will overlap with this method. You can dissolve the output

Comment: ...or drop duplicates

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks. I am thinking where you have an "intersection" zone "D" that is "made up" by polygons A, B, and C. I want to give this intersection polygon "D" its own unique row, and an additional "Intersections" column would be added to the data frame that would list the "contributing" polygons for this intersection polygon, so a string of "A | B | C", and for the intersection zones made by 2 polygons, a string of "A | B" or "A | C", and for intersected zones only made up from one polygon, just a string of "A", "B", or "C", etc. This is my goal, sorry for me not articulating that well!

Comment: Regarding dissolving, I would think I would want to preserve those "intersection" lines rather than remove them through ha dissolve. And regarding dropping duplicates, I am thinking I would rather than dropping duplicates, I would want to consolidate them into one, while still preserving the unique polygon IDs that made up that intersection polygon. So rather than having an "x_id", "y_id", and "z_id" column, there would just be one "IDs" column that is just a string listing each polygon ID that made up that particular intersection zone. Sorry I don't mean to complicate things here!

Comment: Try groupby by geometry and [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby) on ids

Comment: I like this suggestion a lot, though in looking at your code suggestion, I would then try to groupby the geometries and list on ids, but I don't see that the `id` column you created is ever called. We have `id_x` and `id_y`, but I am not sure how we would list them. I was just  thinking to use `intersection_zones = cross.groupby('inter')['id'].apply(list).reset_index(name='polygon_id_list')`, though I don't see an `id` column to actually list by. Or is this the same `id` column as `id_x` and `id_y`? I am just trying to understand how to list by id. Thanks!